# Invoking source-specific callbacks on a merged Observable/Flowable

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to use RxJava to do some common processing on multiple observables. When the processing is done, I'd like to perform some cleanup based on the source of the request and the result.

As a contrived example, here's what I came up with:

```
Set<FileSource> fileSources = Sets.newHashSet(mp3FileSource, pngFileSource, jsonFileSource);
Flowable.fromIterable(fileSources)
    .flatMap(fileSource -> fileSource.getObservable()
        .concatMap(file -> Flowable.fromFuture(ioWorker.saveFile(workRequest)))
        .doOnNext(saveResult-> notifyComplete(saveResult, fileSource)))
    .subscribe();
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to dependency-inject multiple sources that fit a common interface. It seems like a .compose() that does the execution would be a good fit, but that doesn't seem to work well with IoC.

The above solution works, but allows multiple requests to happen on a single ioWorker object. I got around this by explicitly setting the scheduler for observeOn() and the fromFuture() to a single thread.

Is there a better way to do this? It seems like I should be using merge somehow to make a single observable for the worker to subscribe on, but I can't figure out how to preserve the source in that case.

Comment: Have you tried to use the 2-parameter version of `flatMap`? It allows you to set the parallelism of the operator.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. As I understand it, the behavior that I want is for the flatMap to have arbitrary parallelism, but the subsequent concatMaps to all share a parallelism of 1. Setting a parallelism of 1 on the flatMap seems to only subscribe to one source. In this case, I'm assuming the source does not complete.

Comment: @NathanBraid, if you want parallelism, why are you using concatMap?

Comment: I don't want task parallelism. I want the sources to be able to interleave, hence the use of flatMap to expand sources, but only want a single file to be processed by a given worker at a time. Using concatMap should not allow this interleaving, but it's only preventing interleaving on a per-source basis, rather than globally. I understand the behavior of the existing solution, I'm more looking for alternate approaches. As I mentioned, I can get the above solution to work by explicitly limiting parallelism.

Comment: I'm a little confuse with your requirements, assuming that your are subscribing on io Scheduler, all fileSources observables will run in parallel at multiple io thread, while the concatMap observables (the saveFile()) operations will run in parallel to the fileSources Observable, **but** sequentially to each other. Do you agree? what exactly to you want to act differently here?